# WPF - How to bind item in DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I've run into a bit of a problem.  I've created a DataTemplate and put it into App.xaml and I'd like to use it to style my CheckBoxes within a dozen or so ListViews I have.  The particular ListViews each have at least one column with a bool value.

Here's the DataTemplate I made:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="checkBoxDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsChecked="{WhatDoIPutHere?}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I'm trying to use it to replace this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Discovery Date">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding CaseProperty.DiscoveryDate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter},ConverterParameter='datetime'}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

As you can see, I have IsChecked bound to a specific property of an object attached to my ListView.  If I replace it with my template, how do I bind to the IsChecked property of CheckBox in the DataTemplate?

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Comment: I can't see why your binding should change at all, because the instance of the template is bound to the same thing.

Comment: Are you planning on adding more content to checkBoxDataTemplate in your real implementation? Right now it's functionally the same as the inline template so there's wouldn't really be an advantage to adding complexity needed to include different bindings in it.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is using the same data-template in different places and binding its properties to different things?

Comment: If you're trying to re-use this DataTemplate for several Controls, I actually don't think DataTemplates are meant to be that generic. The answer from Vlad will work as long as you only need to bind one Property, but other than that I suggest you create different DataTemplates for different usage. Also, the comment from OJ is spot on

Comment: @All - Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear.  Basically, I'm using datagrids to display some two dozen different objects.  Most of those objects have boolean properties which I would like to represent using checkboxes.  Do I need a datatemplate for each object and property?  I was hoping to make just one template and reused it somehow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've since abandoned this approach.  I don't think DataTemplates are designed to work in this way... oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}"
          IsChecked="{Binding}" />
```

and then set the appropriate `DataContext`.